# Linux Mint broke and I can't get it to work properly again on dual boot

Tags: linux-mint, partition, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I have used Linux Mint 18 with Windows 10 in dual boot since over a year now and never had a problem. Out of nowhere I was unable to boot Linux, seemingly due to a Windows update, because I didn't use Linux for a while. I thought okay nice, I can easily reinstall Linux (19 this time) and use my Timeshift backup to restore my data.

Well, that didn't quite work: Linux got installed but somehow my mouse didn't work. I couldn't get the drivers to work properly and broke Linux again, so "shit here we go again" and an installed it again. My mouse works fine this time but after restarting Linux, I was unable to log into Cinnamon. I type in my password, the screen flashes, and then the login screen comes back. This loop continues forever. So I reinstalled the Cinnamon desktop. That didn't work either. So I reinstalled Linux again. Now I can't even boot into it, because it doesn't show up in the UEFI as boot entry.

**How do you guys handle this kind of situations? Is there an even "cleaner" way to reinstall Linux?**

My drive setup is as follows:

- 1TB HDD for large programs (games etc)
- 4TB HDD for data
- 250GB SSD for Linux Mint only, with `swap`, `/`, `/home`, and `EFI` partition
  (that is the one used by GRUB I guess?)
- 500GB SSD for Windows 10 only, with its own `EFI` partition (I guess it is for the Windows Bootloader only?)
  [image]

As you can see my drives are in a weird order. But that shouldn't matter as far as i know.

One important thing to point out: Before every reinstall of Linux, I deleted, and formated its partitions via Windows, but kept the EFI (GRUB) partition. I just deleted the `ubuntu` folder from the EFI partition and deleted the old UEFI boot entries. Was that a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

It would not have been necessary to reinstall Linux in this situation: Reinstalling grub2 with the help of a live distro would have been sufficient.

That does not help right now, but will save you trouble in the future.

Keep in mind that Windows always wants the first disk.

I have never had an EFI-Partition on any Linux-Disk, so I think you can safely use "whole disk" during installation.  Grub will take care of things afterwards.

And maybe have a look at https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/ if you want to solve this from the windows side.

Comment: So why do I have an EFI partition on my Linux-Disk? I never intentionally created one. Do you suggest I should format the whole Linux-Disk including the EFI partition and reinstall it? Which partition will be used by grub when I do that?

Comment: Just point your Linux-Installer to your Linux-Disk and let the installer use the entire disk.  It will probably ask you where to install grub at some point and you should install to the mbr on the first disk.  You could install it to your linux-disk as well, and then use EasyBCD to point the windows-boot-stuff to grub.

As always: BACKUPS FIRST!

Comment: "you should install to the mbr on the first disk" - So there is an EFI parition on the Windows-Disk, do you mean that partition where i need to install grub?

Comment: MBR is short for "[Master Boot Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)".  That is the first 512 bytes on a disk, but not a partition.  The installer will take care of that.

Comment: I tried to install grub on the Windows-Disk this time but the Linux Mint installer fails and says that grub cannot be installed on that disk. A window poped up and asks where i want to install the bootloader instead.

Comment: What choices does it offer?  You can install it on the Linux-Disk.  If Mint doesn't start then, you will need to go the EasyBCD-Way and let grub be loaded by the windows-bootmanager.

Comment: I tried that, but everything I select (for example "Cancel the installation") and then click "Okay", nothing happens. I cannot close the dialog. Don't know what to do now.

Comment: That is weird.  Do you have the old Mint18-Disk or USB at hand?   Or any other Live-Linux?  Maybe it's an issue with Mint19 and your hardware.  Or maybe something is wrong with the image you downloaded.  Difficult to say without seeing.

Comment: I managed to install Linux on the desired drive now, but I can't find grub anywhere and EasyBCD doesn't let me add Linux by hand because i use EFI. I updated my question so you can see whats up with my drives. I still don't understand what you mean with MBR? I thought MBR and GPT are ways a drive manages its partitions. Therefore every drive has a MBR or a GPT right?

Comment: I opened a more specific question regarding this problem. Have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533390/how-to-install-linux-mint-alongside-windows-on-different-drives-with-different-b).

Comment: One more idea:  do your have a LINUX-Usergroup somewhere near you?  Doing this in person and at your PC is probably more helpful.

Comment: Nice idea but this is not an option because it is a Tower PC. But thank you so much for your ideas!